# Does AWS charge for duplicate objects in an S3 bucket?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

My understanding is that S3 is an object store, and "paths" are really just keys pointing to an object.

If I make a copy of a file in the same bucket, will I incur a cost for both copies of that object?

[This](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/CopyingObjectsExamples.html) seems to indicate that two objects will have different metadata, so they are different -- but AWS also considers "metadata" to be different than "data".

Comment: Duplicating is same as copying. Since you can't create a symbolic link, both the items will incur costs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes you are right
"S3 is an object store, and 'paths' are really just keys pointing to an object." But when you create 2 paths they actually are pointing to 2 different objects (even if objects are exact replicas of each other)

So you will incur cost of storing 2 objects